# Post Using Resource Causes Parameters to be Appended to URL - Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

I have the following service in my Angular App:

```
myAngularApp.factory('myFactory', function($resource, HOST){
    return{
        getThings: function(userId, userToken){
            var connection = $resource(HOST + '/user/mypost/', {'Userid': userId, 'UserToken': userToken, 'Type': 'Read'}, {
                save: {
                    method: 'POST'
                }
            });
            var results = connection.save();
            results.$promise.then(function(data){
                results = data;
            });
            return results;
        }
    }
});
```

In one of my controllers, I call the above factory and its function using

```
myFactory.getThings($scope.someId, $scope.someToken);
```

When I look at the Network pane in developer tools, the POST request is sent with the correct query string parameters, but the URL is appended with the same parameters (a la GET request).  How do I stop the parameters from being appended to my URL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try passing your parameters directly to your `save()` function and remove them from the URL parameters argument in your `$resource` constructor:

```
var connection = $resource(HOST + '/user/mypost/', {}, {save: {method: 'POST'}});

var params = {'Userid': userId, 'UserToken': userToken, 'Type': 'Read'};

var results = connection.save(params);
```

Comment: Is this the only possible solution?